# Fail to move data from one shared folder to another

Tags: network-share, windows-sbs-2008

I have the following problem. I have created some shared folders so that users can backup their data. This was before setting up the AD. Now, after the AD has been set up, we want to move those data to the new user shares that were created. Now I want to move/copy the data I get the following message(see image below) when I am trying to do it from the server and a message like "there is no space left" when I am trying from the client computer. I have to mention that this messages are not shown from the beggining, but some progress is made before failure. Any ideas? It's a bit urgent to make those backups until tomorrow :S

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBS 2008 has shared folder quotas and folder redirection quotas per user enabled by default. My guess is that's what you're running into here. Take a look at the quota settings in the SBS console for your users.

Comment: When I see quotas from sbs console it says "not yet configured" or stn similar. What does it mean? I thought that the default was no quota. Indeed, those folders that appear to be "problematic" are of big size.

Comment: What section of the SBS console are you seeing that in?

Comment: In the meanwhile I foundthe solution. I couldnt locate the setting in the console but I found them on file server managment :)

Comment: Glad to help...